# Tomcat Thread blocking for localhost connection

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I have a head-scratcher that has been bothering be a days now.

I have couple of webapps deployed under tomcat (7/8 doesn't matter, the issue stays) and their interaction is causing me a headache.

**The Flow:**

Lets say I have application A and application B deployed in the same tomcat. Application A receives an outside http request R1, does something and sends another http request to the application B on a same tomcat. After request is sent the R1 thread is put to wait state by Java Object.wait() method.

Application B receives the request R2 send by application A, processes it and send a request to application A.

Application A receives the request R3, does some processing and makes a request R4 to application B again (this is sort of a notification) and wakes up the thread handling R1, who is waiting at this point.

```
X  Req1    A         B
|--------->|  Req2   |
|          |-------->|
|          |  Resp2  |
|          |<........|
|          |  Req3   |
|          |<--------|
|          |  Resp3  |
|          |........>|
|          |  Req4   |
|          |-------->|
|          |  Resp4  |
|  Resp1   |<........|
|<.........|         |
```

**The Problem:**

Everything goes fine except with the notification request R4. This request hangs every now and then. Handling gets stuck when HTTP Connection is waiting for the response code. After a request times out after 30 seconds the application B logs the request received and would return ok. This happens immediately after the request times out.

Hanging happens only if this request R4 is made to Application B located in the same tomcat. If the application B is running on some other server the call works 100% of times. It is also only this one place where the call fails. It is not actual call issue since I could change the notification call to be made any other call in this same place and it would randomly hang up.

Can someone shed some light on this issue and point me to right direction. I'm starting to run out of ideas.

Comment: By `put to wait state by Java Object.wait()`, do you mean in *your* code, you're calling `wait()`? Can we see this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the problem here gave me some new ideas and I started to broaden my scope.

I tried the case also with Jetty and after it gave the same hangup I was sure it was in my code somehow.

Turned out to be that before the R4 is send to the Application B the Application A writes to the HttpServletResponse of the R3.

```
response.getWriter().println(responseContent);
response.getWriter().flush();
response.getWriter().close();
```

Here the closing of the stream was the thing that caused everything to break. I removed the close() call and now the R4 request is working as it should.

I have no idea why the closing of a response stream would make the next new HTTP Request hang like it did...